# Gridview FooterRow textbox text is null when accessing from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with the following columns

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
         <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </FooterTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lbl_name" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "t_Name") %>' />             
       </ItemTemplate>  
       <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" Width="100px" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"t_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
       </EditItemTemplate>        
     </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Created By">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl_tabcreatedby" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "t_CreatedBy") %>' />
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Modify" ShowEditButton="True" />

       <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add a New Name">
           <FooterTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_AddName" runat="server" CommandName="Insert">Add Name</asp:LinkButton>
           </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
```

And then in the Code Behind I am trying to access the txt_Name Textbox as

```
protected void gv_Name_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{             
  string t_Name = ((TextBox)(gv_Name.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_Name"))).Text;
  // Insert Code
}
```

But I am getting null in the string t_Name everytime irrespective of what is the current Text of txt_Name.
However I can get the text if I disable the ViewState for the page. Any explanation.

Comment: try checking if you even get the textbox control or not? just this line:  ((TextBox)(gv_Name.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_Name")))

Comment: Yes I am getting TextBox but Text is null.

Answer (score 2):

I have got around this problem by using an additional variable, see the following:

```
Dim txtBox As TextBox = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtName")
Dim name As String = txtBox.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try getting the textbox by column index, like following:

> ```
> protected void gv_Name_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
> {
>     string t_Name = ((TextBox)(gv_Name.FooterRow.Cells[5].FindControl("txt_Name"))).Text;
>     // Insert Code
> }
> ```

Comment: just to make sure everything is fine, check if ViewState of page is enabled.

Comment: and one more thing, you must be assigning some data to GridView in the page load event, make sure you are assigning datasource inside  if(!Page.IsPostback) { } condition.

Comment: :s how would you get the state of a control after disabling the ViewState.?

Comment: I am also surprised. I tried EnableViewState="false" in the page directive and now I can get the value of the Textbox

Comment: and the other controls on page are working fine after postbacks?

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine. The only thing which I can't understand is what goes wrong when I have ViewState as Enabled.

Comment: that is just weird. no idea. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in gv_Name_RowCommand event

```
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
 {
string t_Name = ((TextBox)(gv_Name.FooterRow.FindControl("txt_Name"))).Text; 
}
```

this should work

Answer (score -1):

i think you data grid is being disconnected from the data source upon post back. If you are sure that data/ data value coming from db is not null.